# Error message: Unresolved variable or type JSON (stringify)?

Tags: json, typescript, variables, stringify

I got this really unexpected error message when trying to do:

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));

Unresolved variable or type JSON
```

Im working in an Angular Typescript file. I have looked on the internet for a solution but nothing really helped. Thanks in advance!